# Synonymizing [free-function] with [non-member-functions]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I've just noticed that there are two separate tags for them.  [free-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-function) also has no tag wiki, [but by definition, it's a non-member function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863328/1950231).  As such, I think they should be synonymized (and to reduce possible confusion, especially with [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free), I suppose [non-member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-member-functions) should be the master).

Comment: Perhaps both should be a synonym of [tag:global]?

Comment: @Mast: No.  Functions within a namespace are not class members nor are they global.  Ditto for local functions (in languages that support those).