# Disambiguate the [free] tag: Multiple possible usages

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Recently I noticed [this off-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809917/i-want-to-know-what-is-the-best-way-to-test-my-website-developed-in-asp-net-mvc) and found that it uses [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) tag, which has description below (you can see in [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free/info)):

> free is a function to deallocate memory obtained from malloc and other
>   functions in C. Do not use this tag to refer to free software. Asking
>   for software recommendation is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you
>   have a question about free software, you can ask
>   here:https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

This tag at the time of writing contains [1,834 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free), some of them even not related with [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) language function as described above or tagged incorrectly. Here are some examples:

[Is any free and mark-able reference to " Symfony 3.4 framework tutorial "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715437/is-any-free-and-mark-able-reference-to-symfony-3-4-framework-tutorial) (off topic)

[Python: Error in python3: free(): invalid size: 0x00000000037e3190](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693663/python-error-in-python3-free-invalid-size-0x00000000037e3190)

[Free spanish speech recognition service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329774/free-spanish-speech-recognition-service) (off topic)

[NodeJS - can I "free" a required module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225841/nodejs-can-i-free-a-required-module)

[Delphi Tokyo Android: How do I get the Free Available Disk Space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552808/delphi-tokyo-android-how-do-i-get-the-free-available-disk-space)

[Free WordPress form plugin with upload files option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344030/free-wordpress-form-plugin-with-upload-files-option)

[Command Line 'free' get only the result from 'total'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49279290/command-line-free-get-only-the-result-from-total)

[Jenkins Swap Space on Slave server - Killed processes to get RAM back but SWAP is not free, How safe is swapoff -a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311773/jenkins-swap-space-on-slave-server-killed-processes-to-get-ram-back-but-swap-i)

There are another possible usages of [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) which do not mentioned yet, hence to avoid further conflicts renaming [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) for disambiguation should be arranged like this example:

- For C/Python `free()` function: [free-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-function)
- For general free memory problems: [free-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-memory)
- For `free` command in UNIX: [unix-free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-free) or [unix-free-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix-free-command)

I'm also aware with [free-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-function) for C/C++ language as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-function), but it still has no wiki and/or usage guidance. Also I found [this request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334703/synonymizing-free-function-with-non-member-functions) but not providing any solutions yet.

If you feel there are better usage examples, please add more suggestions.