# Rename [free] to [free-memory]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request

Somewhat related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372483/disambiguate-the-free-tag-multiple-possible-usages), but that one was asking for a disambiguation.

[free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) is still being misused on the edges. The core concept is on-topic, but the tag name itself is too vague. People use it for anything free, including

- [software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302175/use-tinymce-with-angular-6-without-apikey-free?r=SearchResults&s=20|8.8773)
- [shipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190633/in-woocommerce-how-can-i-make-the-text-for-flat-rate-free-shipping-class-say-f)
- [booking dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740231/sql-find-free-slots-for-booking-system)
- [heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555874/how-to-calculate-heap-free-percent-in-oracle-weblogic-using-command-line) (not memory related)

[free-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-memory) makes more sense. The vast majority are talking about this programming concept and it goes beyond [malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/malloc). This way it can stop being misused.

Comment: What about `free` command in Unix/Linux? It is a specific word

Comment: This tag does not have usage problems, 80% are tagged [c] and 14% are tagged [c++].  Renaming it can only broaden its scope to every programmer having memory problems.

Comment: I can see your point, but it would not be a good idea.

Comment: Just to verify that I interpreted your suggestion correctly, your suggestion is to rename [tag:free] to [tag:free-memory] and broaden its scope so that it's not only about C/C++ but also covers questions about free memory with Unix, Delphi, Heap space, ... ?

Comment: @g00glen00b People are using it for more than C languages anyways. For instance [30 questions are Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfree%5D+%5Bdelphi%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)

Comment: @HansPassant If you want to say that it's not a problem you want to deal with a retag, that's fair enough, but my argument is we can avoid the problem entirely by making a vague tag more specific (new users often don't read excerpts). Moreover, other languages are using it as well (like [delphi]). It won't expand it to *every* memory problem, however. We do have [tag:garbage-collection], which is what a great many languages use (10k for GC, compared to 2k for free).

Comment: @Machavity I noticed that. One more question, why do you want to rename the tag to [tag:free-memory]? Wouldn't it be enough to just change the tag description and wiki of [tag:free] so that it matches with what it's actually used for? (being something about free memory)

Comment: @g00glen00b New users are notorious for not reading excerpts, let alone wikis. That's why I propose tag renames. I've had several problem tags (that were generic like this) stop having problems after renaming them to something more specific (case in point [was carbon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356485/rename-carbon-to-macos-carbon-and-synonym))

Comment: @Machavity I understand that. However, I searched for questions using the [tag:free] tag that weren't about memory, but I could only find 14 results, of which 4 are off-topic in my opinion and should not exist. So either **(a)** the tag isn't misused a lot, in which case I'm worried we might cause more harm when renaming the tag if people are no longer able to find it, **(b)** the tag is being cleaned up regularly and then I understand where this proposal is coming from or **(c)** my search was flawed.

Comment: @g00glen00b Finding it wouldn't be a problem. After you rename you synonym [free] to [free-memory] and it's still there, easy to find. (b) seems to be the case, where it's just being cleaned up. I don't come to Meta for fun or one-off misusage

Comment: Why not alias it to [tag:malloc], and at the same time alias both [tag:calloc] and [tag:realloc] to [tag:malloc] as well? What's the point of such a fine granularity in tags? If you can answer a question about [malloc] you can answer then about [free] and [realloc] too. Or maybe they all need to be aliases to [tag:dynamic-memory-allocation]?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Because [malloc] is mostly specific to C. [C++ apparently tries to avoid using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184537/in-what-cases-do-i-use-malloc-vs-new)

Comment: I'm not sure how that is relevant (and it's not at all true though, C++ has a `std::malloc` in its standard library). `free` only applies to memory allocated using `malloc` and `calloc`, and these functions are all inseparable. You should never use `malloc` without a `free`, and you cannot use `free` if you haven't previously used a `malloc`. I don't see the point of separating them out into separate tags.

Comment: @CrisLuengo We could clean out the other usages if needed and synonym. I'm just trying to cover all possible objections

Comment: Cleaning up the tag is definitely something we should do. I agree that its name is not specific enough, renaming it or synonymizing it would solve that issue. -- I think the new question wizard needs a step where the user must review the tags added, but that is a proposal for another day...

Comment: What about the `free()` function? It technically applies to more than just `malloc()`.

Comment: @JL2210 You mean *alloc family (`malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`,)  ? Well, yes

Comment: @Stargateur `strdup`, `strndup`, etc. But it could also apply to the `free` function itself, such as the behavior when a null pointer or a pointer not previously allocated is sent to `free`.

Comment: @JL2210 Well, this case is a little different first there are not a part of std of C. But that is the documentation that state to use `free()` for these functions and only that allow user to use `free()` on these pointer. So this kind of function must use *alloc family, if they say to use `free()` to release memory.

Comment: @Stargateur `strdup` and `strndup` are part of POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html

Comment: @JL2210 And POSIX is not std of C.

Comment: Could also rename to `[freeeeeeeeeeeeedooooooom!!!]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the tag name: as you know, the primary, C meaning concerns an ubiquitous function called `free`. As far as that is concerned, [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) is a crystalline tag name. From that point of view, [free-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free-memory) is a substantially worse alternative: it looks awkward (like a Wikipedia disambiguation title -- "Free (memory)" -- but without the parentheses) and reads ambiguously (is "free" a verb or an adjective?).

On misuse: from a quick look at the question feed, I count six ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56415903/free-library-for-commercial-use-for-creating-php-7-graphs-without-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190633/in-woocommerce-how-can-i-make-the-text-for-flat-rate-free-shipping-class-say-f), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836652/furnish-free-template-cant-replicate-the-demo), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090835/is-it-possible-to-find-the-current-used-hours-on-the-free-plan-via-the-heroku-ap), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319830/heroku-free-tier-can-a-single-app-spend-all-dyno-quota), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949623/cloud-machines-available-for-free-docker-test)) blatantly mistagged questions among the last hundred [free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/free) questions, spanning a period of six months -- and at least half of those should have been closed. Is that significant misuse? Maybe. Is it significant enough to justify changing the tag to a substantially worse name? Probably not.

All in all, I tend to [agree with Hans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385708/rename-free-to-free-memory#comment701119_385708) on this change not being worth the trouble -- with the caveat that a strong consensus in the other direction among C and C++ contributors (who presumably do the brunt of the curation in this tag) should suffice to override my concerns.

Comment: Perhaps we should add a [free-command] tag for the `free` command (or migrate those questions over to Unix&Linux).

Comment: @JL2210 Such a tag might make sense, though as far as [free] is concerned such question don't look like a big problem (in particular, they also don't justify renaming [free]).

Comment: No, I don't suggest renaming [free], I just think it would be a good idea to create another, separate [free-command] tag.

Comment: Might be useful to know for future cases, but when do you consider misuse of a tag significant enough to justify changing the tag? In this case, about [91 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bfree%5d%20-%5bc%5d%20-%5bc%2b%2b%5d%20-%5bmalloc%5d%20-%5blibc%5d%20-%5bglibc%5d%20-%22malloc%22%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) (or 5%) of the questions appear to misuse the tag, so I guess that isn't enough?

Comment: @g00glen00b Establishing a number like that would require broad and careful analysis, if it is feasible at all. All I'm saying here is that one question slipping through per month doesn't seem to justify this particular renaming. (Also, note that those search results also include questions about the Linux command, which wouldn't be affected by [free-memory], and questions about C-like `free` in other languages, which do fall under the scope of the tag.)

Comment: Hmm, free memory. Is this where I can download more RAM?